# htaccess - redirect to parent folder if folder contains /undefined/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parent

In my .htaccess I want to redirect (301) to the parent folder if the url contains /undefinded/ at the end.
The problem is that the parent folder changes all the time. In other words:

if url contains
        domain.com/any-page/undefined/
make a redirect to
        domain.com/any-page/
So
        domain.com/apples/undefined/ should redirect to domain.com/apples/
        domain.com/bananas/undefined/ should redirect to domain.com/bananas/
        domain.com/peas/undefined/ should redirect to domain.com/peas/
ect.

Can anybody post a htaccess rule to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to match literal `/undefined` in URIs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)/undefined/?$ /$1
```